# Memory leak when switching listview and gridview android

Tags: android

I do switching between gridview and listview in fragment. Current it switches smoothly but when click on switch button many time, memory increase alot and not release.
Please tell me how to avoid increase memory in this case.
Thanks.

Comment: need to see your code

Comment: exactly, without a code sample it is hard to define what is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that You can creating a new adapter every time when you click. So you have many adapters with allocating memory. You have to use one adapter for listview and gridview, or you have to clear adapter allocation , and then creating new one. Remember to clear allocated  resources.